# Why the result from a http call (observable) can be printed but not saved in a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to save the result from a http call in a variable (in a component's attribute). When I subscribe to the observable that wraps the response from the server and print its content, I can see what I expect, i.e. the result is returned. However, when I save it to a variable, it doesn't work - the variable is empty.

InfoComponents

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headertitle = 'abc';
    this.myService.getAnswer(this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params.refid))).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
      console.log("Res is: ", result); // this prints an object with filled fields
    });
    // the if below is skipped because data does not exist
    if (this.data) {
        this.description = this.data.desc;
    }
```

Service:

```
  myService(id): Observable<Info> {
    return this.http.get<InfoWrapper>('...' + id)
    .pipe(map(res => res.data.info[0]));
  }
```

How can I save the result to the variable so that it can be accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of observables. The `subscribe` happens at a later point in time than the `if (this.data)`. If the operation relies on the data, you have to do it inside of the subscribe block like so:

```
this.myService.getAnswer(this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params.refid))).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
      console.log("Res is: ", result); // this prints an object with filled fields
      if (this.data) {
        this.description = this.data.desc;
      }
    });
```